# What is the difference between MSS SP-80 Type 1 and Type 2?

Tags: plumbing, code-compliance

I have a bronze gate valve whose spec sheet says it conforms to MSS SP-80 Type 2.  However, the project standards specify that the gate valve must be MSS SP-80 Type 1.  What is the difference between the two types, anyway?

FYI, the spec sheet for the particular valve in question can be found [here](http://www.milwaukeevalve.com/data/pdf/1169.pdf).

Comment: This seems a bit esoteric for DIY home improvement.  Are these boiler parts?

Comment: @HerrBag Actually, I work for a mechanical contracting firm.  I'm using these as just regular hydronic valves.  The reason I'm asking this here, is because there was nowhere else to ask.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a Type I is a globe valve and the type II is an angle valve.

[image]

Comment: That can't be right, because I have another valve [here](http://www.milwaukeevalve.com/data/pdf/1141.pdf) that is a MSS SP-80 Type 1, and it's still a gate valve.

Comment: I found the chart here, under "Valve specifications Federal" http://www.turnkeyips.com/specifications.html

Comment: I went over the chart, and if you look at some items lower down, what I'm after is under Federal Specification WW-V-54d Class B, Type 1.

Comment: obviously, MSS SP80 type 1 isn't a valve type, per se, since both a gate and a globe valve qualify.

Comment: Some other inconsistency I noticed: the spec book is asking elsewhere for type 3 bronze globe valves, but there is no type 3 bronze globe valve in the table, it skips right to type 4.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out what the difference is:

- Type 1 valves have non-rising stems
- Type 2 (or 3) valves have rising stems

It's basically whether or not the handle moves vertically when you turn it.

Comment: WW-V 54d seems to be the determining spec for gate valves.

Comment: @HerrBag Yes, at least for bronze ones.